# Хранение объекта в общей памяти

Tags: c++, процесс, multiprocessing

Если приложение работает с разделяемой между процессами памятью, может ли оно в этой памяти хранить объект класса? Какие требования предъявляются к этому объекту? Может ли он иметь виртуальные методы? Что произойдёт, если этот объект начнёт динамически выделять память?

Вот пример размещения в общей памяти объекта, в котором, на мой взгляд, подводных камней быть не должно.

```
QSharedMemory InteropMemory("name1");
QSystemSemaphore InteropSemaphore("name2", 1);
InteropSemaphore.acquire();
if (!InteropMemory.attach())
{
    bool created = InteropMemory.create(sizeof(InteropData));
    if (!created)
        qDebug() << InteropMemory.errorString();
    InteropMemory.lock();
    char *data = (char*)InteropMemory.data();
    InteropData *object = new InteropData();
    memcpy(data, object, sizeof(InteropData));
    delete object;
    InteropMemory.unlock();
}
InteropSemaphore.release();

class InteropData
{
public:
    InteropData();
    bool nextPointAllowed();

    int attach();

    void detach(int procNumber);

    void allow(int procNumber);

    void reset();
private:
    bool m_allowNextPoint[INTEROP_MAX_PROC_COUNT];
    bool m_procTerminated[INTEROP_MAX_PROC_COUNT];
    int m_count;
};
```

В дальнейшем в коде этот объект используется так:

```
InteropMemory.lock();
InteropData *object = (InteropData*)InteropMemory.data();
object->allow(1);
InteropMemory.unlock();
```

---

UPD. И ещё вопрос, при освобождении общей памяти не будет вызван деструктор объекта. Можно ли его вызвать самому? Нужно ли в данном случае?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Если приложение работает с разделяемой между процессами памятью, может ли оно в этой памяти хранить объект класса?

Если ответить коротко, то нет, не рекомендовал так делать.

В общей памяти вы можете хранить [POD](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0_%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85) типы.

Данная операция не безопастна не только для общей памяти, но и для обычной памяти:

```
memcpy(data, object, sizeof(InteropData));
```

Т.к. исходя из ООП вы должны вызвать конструктор копирования для этого случай. После вызова метода:

```
delete object;
```

В декструкторе вы уничтожите объекты на которые ссылается "Класс", который вы скопировали строкой выше.

Возможно приведённый выше код даже заработает, но это не безопасный подход, который может не заработать на других платформах/компиляторах.

Также видимо предпологается, что вы ходите передать этот объект в другой процесс. Но как минимум он может ссылаться на адреса памяти старого процесса.

На вашем бы месте я бы копировал в разделяемую память структуру:

```
struct InteropDataStruct
{
    bool m_allowNextPoint[INTEROP_MAX_PROC_COUNT];
    bool m_procTerminated[INTEROP_MAX_PROC_COUNT];
    int m_count;
}
```

А при чтении передавал бы эту структуру в конструктор класса:

```
InteropMemory.lock();
InteropDataStruct *data = (InteropDataStruct*)InteropMemory.data();
object = new InteropData(data);
object->allow(1);
InteropMemory.unlock();
```

Answer (score 3):

> Если приложение работает с разделяемой между процессами памятью, может ли оно в этой памяти хранить объект класса?

да, можно. Используйте placement new

> Какие требования предъявляются к этому объекту?

объект должен понимать, что к нему могут обращаться с разных процессов. А тут появляется много-много особенностей. Самое простое - это синхронизация и обычный мютекс тут уже не поможет. Нужны средства междупроцесовой синхронизации. Но это пол беды. Дело в том, что каждое приложение будет компилировать класс и из-за разных настроек компилятора/линковщика или разных версий компилятора/линковщика объекты будут разные.  А это может выдавать самые различные спецэффекты. Самое простое - это выравнивание. Из-за этого, смещение второго массива и переменной m_count может немного отличаться с точки зрения процесса.

> Может ли он иметь виртуальные методы?

может. Кто же ему мешает. Главное, что бы все правильно было выделенно и настроено.

> Что произойдёт, если этот объект начнёт динамически выделять память?

если он просто будет выделять память - он выделит ее в контексте вызывающего процесса. Другие процессы не смогут получить доступ к этой памяти. Но может выделить в общей памяти. Тогда будет проще.

> И ещё вопрос, при освобождении общей памяти не будет вызван деструктор объекта.

да, не будет

> Можно ли его вызвать самому?

можно. где то так

```
obj.~InteropData();
```

либо, что более правильно - использовать placement delete

> Нужно ли в данном случае?

если использовать placement new и объект не создает сторонних сущностей (открывает файлы, к примеру), то можно и не вызывать деструктор.